# If $E$ is connected then $f(E)$ is also connected

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Theorem: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function, and $E\subseteq X$ be connected, Then $f(E)$ is also connected.

There is a clear proof in my book, But I was wondering if my proof is right roo. Here is mine:

Proof: Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ be two metric spaces. if $E \subseteq X$ is connected, Then $f(E)$ is also connected. By contradiction suppose that $f(E)$ can be written as the union of two separated sets like $A,B$. Now we define $dist$ like this:

$dist(A,B) = inf \{d_2(a,b) | a\in A, b\in B \}$

Then $dist(A,B)$ would be a positive number like $\epsilon > 0$. Now suppose that $a,b$ are two elements in $X$ such that, $dist(A,B)=d_2(f(a),f(b))$. So we found $\epsilon$ such that

$\forall \delta >0, d_1(a,b)<\delta , d_2(f(a),f(b)) \geq \epsilon$. So $f$ is not continuous.

Is my proof right? I dont like this proof, Something tells me that Im making a mistake.

Comment: Note that your proof (if correct) is only valid in the metric setting, so the result is weaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, not being connected and being able to be written as the union of separated sets are not equivalent. If $f(E)$ is not connected, this does not mean it can be written as $A\cup B$ with $A,B$ separated.

By the above comments, the distance, $d_2(a,b)$ does not have to be $\varepsilon >0$ since $A,B$ are not necessarily separated. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ take $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$.

Also, there is no guarantee that $\exists a,b$ such that $dist(A,B)=d_2(f(a),f(b))$. This would mean that there are points which obtain the minimum distance, or obtain the infimum. As an example where this doesn't work, take $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$. The $dist(A,B)$ here is $1$ but, no points are mapped to $1,2$ (assuming this is the image of some mapping).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't understand the first part, I thought that a set is not connected if it can be written as the union of two non-empty separated intervals!(Am I wrong?). And for the second part, What if I choose $dist(A,B) = inf \{d_2(a,b) | a\in \bar{A}, b\in \bar{B} \}$ Then it would not become 0.

Comment: @lino A set is not connected if it can be written as the union of two nonempty *disjoint* sets. Disjoint and separated are different (disjoint means their intersection is empty, as in $(0,1), (1,2)$. Separated means their closures are disjoint, not the case in this previous example even though they are not connected). For the second part of your comment, there are some problems. Where are you taking the closure? What if the closure is connected but the image $f(E)$ is not?

Comment: Thanks a lot, So you are suggesting that my approach is fundamentally wrong? My books approach is something like this(http://www.math.tamu.edu/~tvogel/410/sect111a.pdf) And I understand it well, I was just looking for an other solution.

Comment: @lino (There is one claim in the proof I disagree with. This is that $E=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$. It should be $\subseteq$ instead of $=$). Your approach is not fundamentally wrong. There is just a gap between arbitrary topological spaces and metric spaces. For instance, in a metric space the $\inf$ of distances between two sets $A,B$ can be $0$ without the sets being connected (as I have shown above). If both of these sets are closed then this can not be true but, open and closed are not needed in the proof.